# Is it possible to alternate two input methods in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I know that there is "C-\" to switch input methods, but that allows only one additional input method - for example, by default I have english qwerty layout, and I can alternate between it and dvorak.

But is there some way to do alternation between two other languages with the same ease? For example, if I want to alternate english-dvorak and my native language layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I type `C-u C-\` to select one input method, and once again to select another, I find that every subsequent invocation uses the previous input method as the default input, so switching to the other input method boils down to `C-u C-\ RET`.

Answer (score 7):

To switch between 2 or more alternative input methods quickly, I've added the following code to my `init.el`:

```lisp
;; Input method and key binding configuration.
(setq alternative-input-methods
      '(("russian-computer" . [?\C-\\])
        ("chinese-py-punct" . [?\C-|])
        ("german-postfix"   . [?\C-\M-|])))

(setq default-input-method
      (caar alternative-input-methods))

(defun toggle-alternative-input-method (method &optional arg interactive)
  (if arg
      (toggle-input-method arg interactive)
    (let ((previous-input-method current-input-method))
      (when current-input-method
        (deactivate-input-method))
      (unless (and previous-input-method
                   (string= previous-input-method method))
        (activate-input-method method)))))

(defun reload-alternative-input-methods ()
  (dolist (config alternative-input-methods)
    (let ((method (car config)))
      (global-set-key (cdr config)
                      `(lambda (&optional arg interactive)
                         ,(concat "Behaves similar to `toggle-input-method', but uses \""
                                  method "\" instead of `default-input-method'")
                         (interactive "P\np")
                         (toggle-alternative-input-method ,method arg interactive))))))

(reload-alternative-input-methods)
```

So, to switch to Russian, Chinese or German IME I use <kbd>C-\</kbd>, <kbd>C-|</kbd> and <kbd>C-M-|</kbd> accordingly. And to switch back to English I use the same key as for the current IME (i.e. if I have Chinese IME active, I'll switch back using <kbd>C-|</kbd>).

To configure use `alternative-input-methods` variable. It's a list of conses of an input method name and a key binding.

**Note!** If you activate an IME either by calling `M-x toggle-input-method` or by <kbd>C-u C-\</kbd>, pressing <kbd>C-\</kbd> would switch to an input method according to `alternative-input-methods` variable (in the default configuration Emacs remembers new IME and uses it for <kbd>C-\</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

```
(setq my/input-methods '(nil "some-input-method" "japanese" ))
(defvar my/input-method-switch-counts 0 "a count; more than index")
(make-variable-buffer-local 'my/input-method-switch-counts)
(put 'my/input-method-switch-counts 'permanent-local t)
(defun my/switch-input-method () 
  (interactive)
  (setq my/input-method-switch-counts
        (1+ my/input-method-switch-counts))
  (let ((i (nth (% my/input-method-switch-counts
                   (length my/input-methods)
                   )
                my/input-methods
                )))
    (set-input-method i)  ;;interactive use may set any needed
    )
  ;;(message "IME %s on" current-input-method)
  )

(global-set-key (kbd "C-<SPC>") 'my/switch-input-method)
;;also make sure mode-line-mule-info in mode-line-format to show current input-method in mode-line
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).