# Writing a simple toggle function with Elisp (input-method)

Tags: variables, emacs, toggle, evaluation

So, I have tried the following

```lisp
(defun toggle-input-chinese ()
   (if (equal current-input-method 'chinese-py)
       (set-input-method chinese-sisheng)
     (set-input-method chinese-py)))
```

Now, basically, I want to write either chinese or pinyin. I found no easy way to use toggle between non-standard inputs. Therefore, I decided to write this function and bind to a key.

Ok. My problem is: it raises the error `(void-variable chinese-py)`. I don't know how to equate-predicate the current-method with a listed-method. How can I do it?

-- EDIT

This version is functional.
One can put a list of other inputs in the conditional, and you will be toggling through the ring of languages. Finally, bind it to some key.

It's a simpler way to do it, than supposed here:
[Is it possible to alternate two input methods in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032231/is-it-possible-to-alternate-two-input-methods-in-emacs)

```lisp
(defun toggle-input-chinese ()
  (interactive)
  (if (equal (car input-method-history) "chinese-py")
      (set-input-method 'chinese-py)
    (set-input-method 'chinese-sisheng)))
```

Comment: Try quoting both `chinese-py` and `chinese-sisheng`, just as you did in the `(equal...)` expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing `chinese-py` or `chinese-sisheng` as a variable to function `set-input-method`. Lisp evaluates arguments to a function before invoking the function. It tries to evaluate that variable, but that symbol has no value as a variable.

What you want to do instead is pass the *symbol* `chinese-py` or `chinese-sisheng`, not its value as a variable (it has none).

Try quoting both `chinese-py` and `chinese-sisheng`:

```lisp
(defun toggle-input-chinese ()
   (interactive) ; If you want to use it as a command
   (if (equal (car input-method-history) "chinese-py")
       (set-input-method 'chinese-sisheng)
     (set-input-method 'chinese-py)))
```

This is the same:

```lisp
(defun toggle-input-chinese ()
   (interactive) ; If you want to use it as a command
   (set-input-method (if (equal (car input-method-history) "chinese-py")
                         'chinese-sisheng
                       'chinese-py)))
```

Comment: Ok, just to doccument. I greatly appreciate your help.

There still a change neeeded to be made to make it work, which is 


`(equal (car input-method-history) "chinese-py")`


Because `input-method-history` will be a list of double quoted languages.
`current-input-method` is not used to store the name of the language.

Comment: I see. I know nothing about input methods - I just used your code for that part. I've edited the answer according to your comment.

Comment: I see. I didn't know either. I have just learned and added this information in our discussion.

I'm still having trouble making the toggle... I unable to understand why. It works sometimes. It depends on what input method I'm, when I use the toggle. If I come from exterior modes (aka latin-1 or utf-8), then it will work. If I come from chinese-py or chinese-sisheng, it won't.

Comment: I suggest you pose a separate question that asks something about some help you need now. This question can serve as a question about quoting symbols. To get your code to do what you want, it may require posing and answering multiple questions. Pose only one, specific question per question.